# Permission Denial when using ContentResolver

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

On Android 10,
I am trying to get data from external apps (like file managers, google photo etc) into my app using this guide -
https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive

After receiving the intent in my app, I am trying to open an input stream:

```
InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(CGlobals.context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(receivedURI));
```

It works initially from the Activity specified in the manifest, and even after.

However, I get a Permission Denial error in logcat-

```
Permission Denial: reading com.google.android.libraries.storage.storagelib.FileProvider uri content://com.google.android.apps.nbu.files.provider/2/721 from pid=19038, uid=10264 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()
```

when I am trying to get the input stream from other activities or threads in my app.
After trying for some time, I managed to find that this permission problem appears after I finish the initial activity.
What I can guess from this is, the Android system is granting this permission only as long as the initial activity is not finished.

If what I discovered is true, is this normal or a bug?

Thank you very much.

Comment: How do you forward the uri from first to second activity?

Comment: I pass the uri via the intent : intent.putExtra("uri", imageUri);

Comment: Add a grand read permission flag.